# how to understand <class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io

The following is the code:

```
fin=open("myFile.txt","r") # opening a file creates a file handle

for line in fin:
    print(line)

fin.close() # close file handle
```

My question is: how to understand the TextIOWrapper object fin? I mean, is it safe to say it is something with a sequence structure, where each item of the sequence is a line of your file with "\n" added? What else could I say about it? How do you understand it?

Any comments are greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's not "with `\n` added"; the line contains the newline in your file too; at most, it's converting `\r\n` to `\n` (if it's a file with Windows line endings).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That expression `for line in file` splits (streams more accurately) the file by the new line delimiter until it reaches EOF. Think of it a stream that reads until it's a new line, and then returns the characters it just read.

Comment: so, the "\n" is with each line, as long as it does not reach EOF, right?

Comment: When print line, the print function will add a new line effect automatically.

Comment: That's why, coding this way will print each line separated by an empty line.

Comment: I don't think it adds a newline but I do think it includes a newline

Comment: @GarriganStafford: The iterator includes the newline (unless it's the last line of the file and it's not newline terminated), using `print` to echo adds another.

Answer (score 1):

File-like objects are [iterators](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator) that produce a line of text on each iteration. Iterators in general just means "things you can loop over exactly once"; files differ from this pattern on insofar as they can (depending on what the represent) be `seek`ed, which would reset the iterator to a new position in the file.

To be clear, they are *not* sequences; the term "sequence" has specific meaning, and includes the ability to index it, iterate it multiple times in a row or in parallel, all without manually fixing up state.